# vba function "sendkeys" does not send anything

Tags: excel, vba, sendkeys

It seems that "sendkeys" is only good for turning off your numbers lock. It does not appear to do anything else. I've tried many different ways to simply write random characters to notepad with no success. My only hunch is this ability has been disabled by a recent Windows update as it used to work fine until last week. Below is some example code. Does anyone know how to get it to send keys again?

```vb
Public Sub WriteToNotePad()

    Dim vReturn As Variant
    vReturn = Shell("NotePad.exe", vbNormalFocus) 'open notepad

    AppActivate vReturn 'ensure notepad is active
    Application.Wait (Now() + TimeValue("00:00:03")) 'wait a few seconds
 
    SendKeys "You should see this in notepad", True
   
End Sub
```

Comment: `SendKeys` is almost worthless. Why not just write a text file? You could open it in notepad. Your code actually works for me. The fact that it works for me but not you illustrates one of the drawbacks of `SendKeys`: it is fragile. It will sometimes work but not other times, in ways that are hard to debug. There is too much dependence on just what your OS is up to when the code runs.

Comment: The fully-qualified member call is `Excel.Application.SendKeys`; the function doesn't exist in global scope, it belongs to the `Excel.Application` instance that's hosting your VBA project - it will only ever "send keys" to the Excel application. Also, `SendKeys` is really a last-resort thing ;-) ...you don't need `SendKeys` to write to a text file and then open it in Notepad

Comment: @MathieuGuindon I'm not quite sure what you mean by "it will only ever "send keys" to the Excel application". OP's code actually works for me -- sending keystrokes to notepad.

Comment: @JohnColeman ugh see, that's *also* part of why `Application.SendKeys` is annoying.. a member call against an in-process object that crosses process boundaries... so it just sends keystrokes to whatever window has focus... makes it even more frail than I thought it already was!

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. The SendKeys function is a small but critical part of a relatively complex spreadsheet that saves our people much time. It actually opens another application & performs all the arduous data entry tasks. The spreadsheet is approximately 6 times faster than manually performing the task. I only used notepad to troubleshoot.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon I agree that it is frail. The only time I ever used `SendKeys` with a certain amount of success was to script Derive (a computer algebra system which had no API) from Excel. Even then I had to constantly tweak the timings. Texas Instruments dropped support from Derive, and I then dropped `SendKeys` from my toolkit. It is an exercise in frustration. Unfortunately, there are still legacy applications which lack any API, so sometimes it is still needed.

Comment: @JohnColeman \*an exercise in *patience* ;-)

Comment: @JoeBeck VBScript itself has a `SendKeys`, so with the proper reference (or late binding) you could perhaps use it rather than Excel's. Other than that, perhaps throw in some random `DoEvents`, perhaps activate the app a second time, and experiment with a larger time delay.

Comment: Ha, sticking a `DoEvents` somewhere between the `AppActivate` and the `SendKeys` call might actually work

Comment: @JohnColeman thanks for the ideas. I started with DoEvents, re-activation, & various times. But ended up calling a VBS file to get the functionality back. Thanks again!

Comment: @JoeBeck I'm glad that it worked out.

Comment: @JohnColeman , this is my 1st & only question. I believe I should "vote up" your response or "check it as the answer," but I see no controls for that. Maybe it's because my account isn't fully unlocked yet, but you get should get credit.

Comment: @JoeBeck Thanks. Comments are not answers. I'm glad that my comments helped you, but I tend to only post answers when I can actually post code which I have verified works. In this case, it was impossible (since I didn't know how to replicate the problem). Stack Overflow is a good resource. Hopefully this won't be the last. Consider answering some questions as well. I find that it is a very good way to learn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used a computer that didn't get the Office 365 update & the code worked fine. So I'm certain that's the problem. To fix it, I used John Coleman's suggestion to write a VBS file instead & then call that script from the VBA code.

From the above example, change this:

```
SendKeys "You should see this in notepad", True
```

To this:

```
Call Shell("wscript C:\writeToNotepad.vbs", vbNormalFocus)
```

And the VBS file would be saved in that location with that name & with this content:

```
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WshShell.SendKeys "You should see this in notepad"
```